# BlueHost Rails Hosting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, bluehost

I just finished a rails app that I want to host on BlueHost. Its given me issues. I am told I ve to apply for SSH Access but I am in Ghana. So I don't know! can anybody help me

Answer (score 1):

I think you should consider SSH access and getting it to work. think also about the fcgi files

Answer (score 0):

You can CHAT directly via Bluehost website to ask them for SSH. You will need extra money for SSH service.